# Как правильно использовать gettext в web-проектах

Tags: python, i18n, веб-программирование

Подскажите как правильно использовать интернационализацию в web-проектах. 
В примерах приведена следующая схема:

```
from gettext import translation
lang = 'ru_RU'
tl = translation(__name__, 'locale', languages=(lang,))
_ = tl.gettext
```

Это что получается данные строки мне придется дублировать в каждый модуль web-проекта и передавать переменную `lang`?

Спасибо.

P.S. Хорошо бы админы метку `gettext` добавили.

Answer (score 1):

Даже если так, что мешает вынести это в отдельный файл и импортировать из него только `_`?

Comment: Думал, что есть более красивое решение.

Comment: Куда ещё красивее?

    from mygettext import _

    text = _(u'Текст')

Импортировать `_` не из своего `mygettext`, а из «их» `gettext`? А какая разница?